# Выделение строки в тексте для чтения

Tags: windows, клавиатура, мышь

Знаю, что в режиме изменения содержимого с помощью мыши и клавиатуры можно комбинацией "Ctrl + left-click", поставив курсор в желанную строку, выделить 1 строку. Хочу узнать, можно ли такой же комбинацией "клавиатура + мышь" выделить только 1 строку в **читаемом** мною тексте(например, текст в статье в wikipedia).
Не обессудьте за не IT-вопрос. Всем добра)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой же - нельзя, разве что самому писать утилиту, перехватывающую события от мыши и клавиатуры.
Я использую сочетание Shift+ стрелка вниз. Выделяет ровно одну строку с позиции, где находится курсор мыши.